# apache rewrite - remove www and keep path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website that operates in two URLs:

```
http://sub.domain.com/
```

and

```
http://www.sub.domain.com/
```

I would like to unify the URL and use only the version without www.
But Google also has links to versions with www that are linking to a specific article (the URL of the path). For example:

```
http://www.sub.domain.com/folder/some.html
```

I want to redirect visitors so as to remove www prefix from address and keep path to article. Using the example from above rewrite URL to:

```
http://sub.domain.com/folder/some.html
```

**Let's clarify:**

I want:

```
http://www.sub.domain.com -> http://sub.domain.com
```

and

```
http://www.sub.domain.com/folder/some.html -> http://sub.domain.com/folder/some.html
```

After apply rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I get:

```
http://www.sub.domain.com -> http://sub.domain.com
```

^^ it works fine :)

and

```
http://www.sub.domain.com/folder/some.html -> http://sub.domain.com
```

^^ it works wrong :(

My other current htaccess rules: http://pastebin.com/C74u7MGL

Answer (score 1):

I generally recommend to use REQUEST_URI instead of the often seen ^(.*)$ and $1:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Advantages:

- REQUEST_URI correctly preserves paths with missing trailing slashes (which $1 does not do). So `olddomain.com/path` will redirect to `newdomain/path` perfectly. With $1 only `olddomain.com/path/` will redirect to `newdomain/path/` but a path segment with missing trailing slash will be removed.
- REQUEST_URI correctly preserves any query strings, which would require an additional QSA flag with the $1 solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It does not work as I expect. If you use an address

www.sub.domain.com it's redirects me to sub.domain.com

and that's ok. But if I use 

http://www.sub.domain.com/folder/some.html browser redirects me to main page http://sub.domain.com, not to http://sub.domain.com/folder/some.html.

Comment: That means you have a conflicting rule somewhere because my rule does not match and do anything unless you have `www.` in the domain name. Post your current rules and check if you have multiple htaccess files.

Comment: My htaccess rules:
http://pastebin.com/C74u7MGL
I have not multiple htaccess files.

Comment: With my rule disabled (add `#` before them) can you reach `sub.domain.com/folder/some.html`? If not, problem lies elsewhere. Check if you have `/folder/.htaccess` because your root `htaccess` doesn't redirect either. Although, it has a rule that says if `/component/any-page.php` (or html etc.) serve `index.php` instead. But, even that wouldn't redirect i.e. your browser url should remain the same.

Comment: Yes, with your rules or without it I can access sub.domain.com/folder/some.html directly.

Comment: Just for testing, can you force the path by changing the rule to `... http://sub.domain.com/folder/page.html ...`? Do you reach your html page now?

Comment: You mean 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/folder/page.html [R=301,L]`
??
If I set this rule every url that contains 'www' is redirected to http://sub.domain.com/folder/page.html

Comment: That's great. That means the rule's working as expected. The .htaccess file that you're adding these rules to, in which directory does it reside? Can you explain you directory structure a bit? Because the rule is quite simple and it **[works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18293321/1237040)**. There has to be something peculiar about your setup that's breaking it.

Comment: No, it's doesn't work as I expected. I add this rules to htaccess in root directory. My directory structure is virtual and is created based on content (this is Joomla CMS). I want rule to the removal 'www' URL was applied to each direct URL.

Comment: I think that the rules of my htaccess from line 8 to 15 doing mess up in behavior of website.