# htaccess rewrite migrate different domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I change the base domain of an incoming link using htaccess module rewrite?

Incoming url:

```
www.foo.com/bar?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Rewritten url:

```
www.newFoo.com/bar?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Apache webserver should simply rewrite all of its incoming urls, on the webserver itself no websites are saved anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory of the server hosting `www.foo.com`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newfoo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer, I will have a look at it the next days.